# Redis MEMORY USAGE & INFO MEMORY

Tags: redis

MEMORY USAGE KEY gives the memory in bytes that key is taking(https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage)

If I sum up the values returned by the command by all of the keys in redis, should it sum up to one of the memory stats returns from INFO MEMORY ?

If yes. Which one would it be?

1. used_memory_rss
2. used_memory_rss_human
3. used_memory_dataset

Answer (score 3):

No, even if you sum up that output from `MEMORY USAGE`, you will not get to the sums reported by `INFO MEMORY`.

`MEMORY USAGE` attempts to estimate the memory usage associated with a given key - the data but also its overheads.

`used_memory_rss` is the amount of memory allocated, inclusive of server overheads and fragmentation.

`used_memory_dataset` attempts to account for the data itself, without overheads.

So, roughly: `used_memory_dataset` **<** sum of `MEMORY USAGE` **<** `used_memory_rss`